# Jqgrid `columnChooser` bootstrap4 supporting css

Tags: bootstrap-4, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid 5.3+ version in bootstrap 4. but when I am using `columnChooser` that time CSS does not reflect proper. because of bootstrap 4 theme is not yet matching. when i will call UI theme then it works proper. but i want in bootstrap 4 version. if you have any example of somewhere then, please let e know then I can get help to write css code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Column Chooser is available only with jQuery UI Theme.

One possible solution is to use Column Menu, which is available in Bootstrap4 and jQuery UI theme. [Demo here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/functionality/bootstrap4/).